# Why classes are not serializable by default in .Net?

Tags: .net, serialization, types

Developers have to 'opt in' for making classes serializable by explicitly using `SerializableAttribute`. What could go wrong if classes were serializable by default?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**I would assume that classes are not serializable by default because there's no guarantee that a dump of the object's state to a stream using Reflection even makes sense.** What if your object holds an open connection to a database or communication port? Whenever a new object was constructed by deserializing an instance of the previous object, you would end up with a useless object.

Plus, you have to consider that whenever a class is serializable, the runtime insists that all of its member variables be serializable as well, unless they are explicitly marked otherwise. It's much easier to make serializability an opt *in* functionality for developers, rather than forcing them to opt *out* certain members.

And finally, you might have certain fields in your class that contain private or sensitive information. Having to explicitly mark classes as serializable ensures that you don't accidentally expose the details of something (whether it be the data or your implementation) to the world that you didn't mean to be public.

Answer (score 4):

Serializable classes imply that they have some kind of state that can be written to an external location and read again. For a lot of classes that doesn't make any sense at all - what kind of state does a Thread have, that you could successfully serialize?

It's a little bit philosophical but by convention the default *type* of a class is not serializable, unless you explicitely define "this class can be serialized".

Answer (score 3):

IMO [Serializable] is confusing, largely because it is **not** actually required by most serialization. By that I mean: there is more code using XmlSerializer (includes asmx), DataContractSerializer (includes WCF), JavaScriptSerializer (includes MVC's JsonResult), or things like protobuf-net etc. [Serializable] is mainly BinaryFormatter, which is (from what I see) in definite decline. and with many good reasons.

As for why: other answers address this, but it doesn't always make *sense* to serialize something. Sure *entity* objects can act as DTO, but that is hard to detect in a robust way.

So IMO there is negligible impact on whether I is [Serializable] or not, but I do agree with the default: you should *know* that you are planning to serialize something. In some cases this serialization means extra work (particularly as some serializers don't run the ctor/init code, so you need to know to prepare fields appropriately).

Answer (score 3):

The Liskov Substitution Principle implies that if a class is serializable, all derived classes should be serializable as well.  If classes were by default serializable, it would be very difficult to derive non-serializable classes without violating the Liskov Substitution Principle.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably better to mark all classes as serializable unless:

- They will never cross an application domain. If serialization is not required and the class needs to cross an application domain, derive the class from MarshalByRefObject.
- The class stores special pointers that are only applicable to the current instance of the class. If a class contains unmanaged memory or file handles, for example, ensure these fields are marked as NonSerialized or don't serialize the class at all.
- Some of the data members contain sensitive information. In this case, it will probably be advisable to implement ISerializable and serialize only the required fields.

Ref:[Object Serialization in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question. He is wanting to know what could happen if everything was serializable by default, not when it's appropriate to serialize.

Comment: This is exactly the answer for this question :-D

Comment: BTW, I think this advice is exactly the wrong way round. It never makes sense to mark a class as serializable unless that actually makes sense, the class *will* need to support it, and is written in a way that supports it.

Comment: -1 - doesn't answer the question. "What could go wrong" and "why not serializable by default". You've answered "When should and shouldn't I mark things as serializable".

Comment: @Rob leaking sensitive information isn't the answer to your question?? and doesn't it one of reasons we use ModelView's instead of exposing Model to clients??

Comment: @DownVoters I don't understand downvoters. cause the answer EXPLICITLY list the situations where we shouldn't make a class Serializable. It means that Making all classes Serializable by default is not a right decision to make and could be harmful.

Comment: Another reason is that It's meaningless to serialize a static class, and you can't restrict AttributeUsage to consider modifiers.

Comment: +1, May be it's not explicit answer to the question but, the reasons wrote by Jani, Is the exact reasons for the "Why not serialized by default".