# How to deploy whole solution in Visual Studio 2012 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I have this project called NopCommerce, What I want is to publish it's whole solution. Here is a screenshot for you reference.

[image]

Everytime I publish Nop.Web I get this errors

[image]

I have many folders and projects in this solution so can anyone help me on deploying this kind of project? I am new with this, also there is no creating of set up unlike in Visual Studio 2010..

Thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: You have many apps, but which one are deployable and which are just class libraries?

Comment: You want to deploy it on IIS or production server?

Comment: @Kamo Nop.Web is my start up project, everytime I publish it error occurs, it's some kind of dll's are not found, dll from other class libraries I think.

Comment: @AmneshGoel Want to deploy it on a production server.

Comment: can u add that error in your questions?

Comment: Did you try following the [nopCommerce installation instructions](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/Installing+nopCommerce)?

Comment: @eljon_i3 Based on the first error, you may want to look into this (old version of VS; but should be the same with VS2012) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374203/sgen-failure-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-an-assembly-with-an-incorrect-format-i

Comment: @eljon_i3 Can you post your .csproject for Nop.Services, Framework and Web? This error clearly states that you references some DLL in the wrong way.

Comment: @AmneshGoel I can't see the update on your question.

Comment: Did you do a google search with exact error message? I found following q&a mostly close to your problem. https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a&ved=0CB4QFjABahUKEwj0x5vGkPXHAhXCF6YKHQcjCm4&usg=AFQjCNHdZocJHyPGFOCy-BBdG9WoaXeJBg&sig2=oXayceWe8OR0nsfRY-9aFA