# sgen serialization assembly not signed

Tags: .net, asmx, .net-assembly, xmlserializer, sgen

I have been reading for the past two days about how to make asmx web service first call quicker.

after tracing and testing i realized that the service is doing nothing on initialize so after reading a couple of answers on that matter, the xmlserialization assembly make sense to do, at least to tick one of the possible solutions.

the Issue is that the service is a third party service and i only have the dll's for that service. i tried to generate the xml serialization assembly but i get the error:

`generated serialization assembly is not signed please specify strong name key file via/compiler:/keyfile switch but i am not sure how.`

is it possible to extract the xmlserialization assembly or i need to the source code for such task?

does what i am trying to do make sense or i am just mislead or misunderstanding the whole thing. any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We had this same issue with SGEN using a hosted Build Controller. The builds worked fine for **DEBUG** mode, but not **RELEASE**. After [reading this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187464/175679) it made sense that we just need to turn off SGEN serialization under **Project Properties -> Build -> Output** section for the **RELEASE** solution configuration (*or any other Non-DEBUG solution configuration you are using*).

#### Disable SGEN XMLSerialization Assembly Generation

[image]

You state you need to generate the serialization assemblies - in our case we didn't, but I'm not sure how to tell the CS compiler which keyfile to use for the SGEN MSBUILD action.