# ASP.NET 4.5 Web App mixed mode assembly built against v2.0.50727

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I'm getting this error in my Web Application in the SGEN file, after I add a web reference to a third party tool.

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

I found this solution but I don't believe that app.config can be added to a Web App. [Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018924/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v1-1-4322)

I added this to the web.config but it didn't help.

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
</startup>
```

I also added this to the sn.exe.config file, but that didn't help either:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: Project-> Right Click-> Properties-> Build->Generate Serialiazation Assembly. Change Value here from "Auto" to Off and build again.

I am not exactly sure why this works but you can read more on generating serialization assembly in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187464/2607777) stackoverflow answer.